# Displaying XML file on localhost server with express JS

Tags: xml, firebase, express

```js
//requiring dependecies
var express = require('express');
var builder = require('xmlbuilder');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
var serviceAccount = require('./xmltest-affa7-e92e88a0dc7b.json');
//initializing service account
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});
//firebase database output
var newarray = []

function CreateXML(newjson) {
  //outputing JSON to console in a clean view for the developer
  //console.log('json= ' + JSON.stringify(newjson))
  //console.log('length = ' + newjson.length)
  var i;
  //Start of xml file 'array'
  var array = builder.create('array')
  //Documents are being pulled through firebase in this case thier are 4
  for (i = 0; i < newjson.length; i++) {
    //Firebase collection format to output to console
    var type = '',
      value = ''
    switch (newjson[i].type) {
      case 'string':
        type = 'string', value = newjson[i].stringvalue;
        break;
      case 'integer':
        type = 'integer', value = newjson[i].integervalue;
        break;
      case 'real':
        type = 'real', value = newjson[i].realvalue;
        break;
      case 'boolean':
        type = newjson[i].booleanvalue.toString();
        break;

      default:
        break;
    } //XML format for console
    array.e('dict')
      .e('key', 'Key').up()
      .e('string', newjson[i].name).up()
      .e('key', 'Value').up()
      .e([type]).r([value]).up()
    //making xml readable
    array.end({
      pretty: true
    });
    newarray.push(array)

  } //outputing xml to console
  console.log(newarray.toString())
}

// firebase utils
var json = []
var db = admin.firestore();
// gathering the data from firebase collection
db.collection('xmltest')
  .get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      const data = {
        'portalid': doc.data().portalid,
        'name': doc.data().name,
        'type': doc.data().type,
        'integervalue': doc.data().integervalue,
        'realvalue': doc.data().realvalue,
        'booleanvalue': doc.data().booleanvalue,
        'stringvalue': doc.data().stringvalue,
      }
      //pushing JSON to console
      json.push(data)
    })
    // function to convert json to xml
    CreateXML(json)
  })
  //catching errors when present
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error))
  });
//Outputting xml to browser
var app = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
  res.send(array);
});
//Server start on 8888
var server = app.listen(8888, function() {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log("We're live on:", port);
});
// Firebase Database output 
/*
    {'portalid': '1111', 'name': 'showHomeIcon', 'booleanvalue': 'false', 'type':'boolean' },
    {'portalid': '1111', 'name': 'motionResetPeriod', 'stringvalue': '1', 'type':'string' },
    {'portalid': '1111', 'name': 'motionResetPeriod', 'integervalue': '2', 'type':'integer' },
    {'portalid': '1111', 'name': 'motionResetPeriod', 'realvalue': '1.0', 'type':'real' },
  ]
*/
```

Here is the source code if someone can help that would be grateful because this has been messing with me for a couple of days.

-- Basis of issue --

I am trying to automatically update iPads for a specific application using XML files. I have never done work with XML before so this is a first for me as a junior developer.

I had got it to a point where the XML could output to the console but couldn't get it to output to the localhost server.

If someone could assist me with this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: `var array` is declared inside `function CreateXML` and is not global variable.  In your `app.get`, you are trying to return `array` instead of `newarry.toString()`

Comment: @JamesPoag - Thanks for the response i'll update the code and try that now :)